# CMS pages showing under product category dropdown

Tags: category, cms

I created navigation links for CMS pages like AboutUs, Contact, How-it-Works etc using the rewrite URL method for categories. The page links are now showing and working on the home page. But now, the issie is that these CMS pages are also showing under category drop down. But they are not product categories but static pages. How to remove them from category dropdown ?

Comment: these CMS page links are showing on the category page as one of the product categories

Comment: ISN'T THERE ANY SOLUTION, PEOPLE !!!!

Comment: In category edit section you can set it as display in navigation to No